# Dynamic generation of stylesheets added to Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, mozilla, gecko

One can use the [nsIStyleSheetService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIStyleSheetService) in Firefox to load and register stylesheets which apply in a similar way to `userstyle.css`; they are applied to every page loaded.  However, this service takes `sheetURI`, which is a URI pointing to a static file to be included as a stylesheet.

Is there a way I could actually generate this stylesheet in Javascript instead, on-the-fly?  Or would there be another interface which allowed me to register a JS callback to output the desired stylesheet to apply, instead of a sheet URI?

Comment: can't you use a data-url for it?

Comment: @Gerben Could you elaborate on this solution, preferably as an Answer to the Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the CSS in JS, then base64 encode it and prepend `data:text/css;base64,`
Then, use this as the URI.

For example: `body{background:red;}`
Becomes: `data:text/css;base64,Ym9keXtiYWNrZ3JvdW5kOnJlZDt9`

Comment: Ah, and this would allow the JS registering the sheet to register what it had just generated and so it would be dynamic!  Got it.  I'll try that, thanks!